# Add style to ImageButton dynamicaly

Tags: android, dynamic, imagebutton

I have added a imagebutton dynamically to my Tablerow, now i want to define the style for the image button to a style that i have previously defined. I have tried the setTheme method that doesnot seem to work

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k after a lot of searching this is what i found and it works perfectly.

1) if you want to create a button/imagebutton/anyView at runtime with a predefined style the you can do so just follow the steps below

2a) Create a new xml file in res/layout and put that one element you want to create for example I wanted to create a minusButton. This is minusb.xml in res/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            style="@style/MinusButton"/>
```

2b) Then add the following lines to your java activity code where you would like to create it

```
ImageButton bt = (ImageButton) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.minusb, null);
bt.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0f));
    tr.addView(bt);
```